# Sonar Radar in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, raycasting

I want to make a sonar radar in my 3D game just like in real life.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JInV.png

The green bar with the black borders is moving properly in a circle. I want to cast a ray from it as it is moving in a circle and get back information when it hit something (detect enemies). Also translating this information on the sonar itself as a red ping.

The code for the 360 rotation
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTQdh.png

Comment: Have you seen this? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J0gmrgpx6gk

Comment: I was following this tutorial, but he is using his own set ups and he is making it in a 2D game he is casting a 2D ray

Comment: you'd better post codes you have and the problem you are facing.